# Modifying an IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T> when passed to a class using generic types

Tags: c#, generics, collections, ienumerable

I am having a bit of trouble in modifying my IEnumerable<> value when using generic types.
Here is a bit of code to start with:

```
public class ParameterArray<TEnumerable, TType> : IParameterArray<TEnumerable, TType> 
    where TEnumerable : ICollection<TType>    // Note that I have tried with IEnumerable<TType> instead of ICollection<TType>, but did not really help
{
    public ParameterArray(TEnumerable value, TType minValue, TType maxValue)
    {
        MinValue = minValue;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
        Value = value;
     }

    private TEnumerable _value;
    public TEnumerable Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
           ICollection<TType> checkedValue;

           // Here I want to check the range before setting the value
           // Note that Value can be of type int[], float[], bool[], byte[]
           
           // I have tried many work around, but for some reasons, I am never able to update _value
           for (int idx = 0; idx < value.Count(); idx++)
           {
               // Backup value after range limiting
               checkedValue.Add(CheckRange(value.ElementAt(idx)));
            }

            // Would like to save these new values in _value, but not sure how to
            _value = checkedValue as TEnumerable;  // Or (TEnumerable)checkedValue;     // !!! Breaking here at runtime - Cannot convert from one type to the other
        }
    }

    public TType CheckRange(TType value)
    {
        TType retValue = value;

        if (value != null)
        {
            // Restrict range to Min/Max
            if (Comparer<TType>.Default.Compare(MaxValue, value) < 0)
                retValue = MaxValue;
            else if (Comparer<TType>.Default.Compare(MinValue, value) > 0)
                retValue = MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Value cannot be null: Range is {MinValue} to {MaxValue}");
        }

        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Somehow, I cannot back up my ICollection into my _value (which is a TEnumerable). However, I do not quite get the reason considering I have declared TEnumerable to be derived from ICollection (ie. where TEnumerable : ICollection)

I have tried multiple approaches, but they all lead to the same issue of not being able to assign my result to _value.

Any suggestion would be welcome.
Maybe I need something else than: where TEnumerable : ICollection

### EDIT and SOLUTION

As suggested by @nvoigt, I have reformated my class so that it does not take a TEnumerable as input. This extra layer of abstraction created extra complexity that made everything difficult to work with.
Here is the resulting solution:

```
public class ParameterArray<TType> : ParameterBase, IParameterArray<TType> 
{
    public ParameterArray(IEnumerable<TType> value, TType minValue, TType maxValue)
    {
        MinValue = minValue;
        MaxValue = maxValue;
        Value = value;
     }

    private IEnumerable<TType> _value;
    public IEnumerable<TType> Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
           IList<TType> checkedValue = new List<TType>();
           
           for (int idx = 0; idx < value.Count(); idx++)
           {
               // Range limiting
               checkedValue.Add(CheckRange(value.ElementAt(idx)));
            }

            // Back up the updated value
            _value = checkedValue.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public TType CheckRange(TType value)
    {
        // Unchanged
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `ICollection<TType> ckeckedValue = default;` ... doesn't make sens ... it's `null` (and `ckeckedValue.Add(...)` wil cause NPE) ... ***also, define "not working"***

Comment: hint  ...just  make `_value` a `List<TType>` ...

Comment: after edit: you can obviosuly short the setter to `_value = new List<TType>(value.Select(CheckRange));` ...

Comment: @Selvin, no _value is supposed to be an Array

Comment: ... let me guess ... you are casting `Value` to `T[]` ... you will shoot your foot with such code ... better you would use `Vaue.ToArray()` ... then `_value` can be `List<T>` ... but even if you wana shoot yourself you still can use `new List<TType>(value.Select(CheckRange)).ToArray()` :D

Comment: @Selvin, not sure what you mean. I just always pass an array value at construction. These values always come in as int[], float[], etc. They are never lists, hence the reason not to convert them to Lists

Comment: your interface (not interface per se but what class reveal to public `ParameterArray`) is `IEnumerable<T> Value` ... for user of `Value` should be no different if underalay value is stored as `T[]` or `List<T>` as long as user wil get `IEnumerable<T>` ... if you change setter to the code I add ... it will still works ... untill you would try to cast `Value` to `T[]`

Comment: @Selvin, I see what you mean, thanks for the tip, still learning

Comment: see ... [still working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yxR5Qj) :)

Comment: @Selvin, oh that's very neat. Is there any flow in doing it this way or is that what you are recommending to do?

Comment: It's up too you ... I think it's almost the same but with less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ckeckedValue as TEnumerable
```

Let's see. Assuming I make `TEnumerable` an `int[]` and `ckeckedValue` is an `ICollection<int>` then your compiler is right... you cannot use the `as` operator to create an array from an `ICollection` of the same base type. That does not work, generics or not.

I cannot really suggest a good approach. If it were me, I'd scrap the generic enumerable part and make it either a `List<>` or an `Array<>` and be done with it. If you have explicit constraints that *require* that part to be generic, you should probably post them with the question, so we can suggest a different solution based on those constraints.

Comment: Thanks for you input. So you wouldn't declare the class as a ParameterArray<TEnumerable, TType>?

Comment: No, I would declare it as `ParameterArray<T>` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and min and max in the constructors and builds it's own list. I mean you produce copies anyway after your first call to add, you can as well do it right from the start.

Comment: And that will allow me to instantiate the class this way? new ParameterArray<new int[3]{1,2,3}>

Comment: Not, it would allow you to use it this way: `new ParameterArray(new[]{1,2,3}, 1, 9);`

Comment: It does seem to work. Thanks again for the suggestion. Redefining my class as you suggested is the way to go. I have been struggling with these generic types for quite some time now and wish I had your input before. You solved 2 problems in one go! Very much appreciated!